# Like query not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

like query is not working i am not able to find out issue here is query given

@radaccnt=Salammobile::Radacct.all.where(CallingStationId LIKE currentuser.salammobilenumber  ).order('AcctStartTime')

Answer (score -1):

i think the issue here is the wild card.

@radaccnt=Salammobile::Radacct.all.where("CallingStationId LIKE %#{currentuser.salammobilenumber}%").order('AcctStartTime')